# span 100% height of parent button

Tags: css, button, height

I have the following markup

```
<button class="filter"><div class="radio"><div class="circle"></div></div> <span>Account Management</span></button>
```

and CSS

```
.filter {
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.filter span {
    background: $leithyellow;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    float: left;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

I cannot get the span to expand to 100% height of the button. Can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heights apply only if the heights are defined properly for the ancestors. If you want the height to work, that's a tricky one. You can use one of my favourites, but you need to make sure it works in all the cases:

1. Give `position: relative;` to the parent.
2. Give `position: absolute;` to the element that needs full `height` and `width`.
3. Give the element, `0` values for all the sides.

**Snippet**

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.parent .child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, it is noted that this can also work, if you give:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.parent .child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
</div>
```

One good part about this approach is, you don't need to use the dangerous `calc`:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.parent .child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 60px;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
</div>
```

> **Note:** On a related note, you can also have a look at this question and answer: [Calc() alternative to fixed side bar with content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34570812)

Comment: comprehensive answer thanks. I was pretty determined to keep the elements relative but this works well.

Answer (score 12):

1. Set `display: flex` to the parent
2. Set `align-self: stretch` for the child

This will stretch the height of the child div/button to fit the height of its parent without doing any trick.

By using `position: absolute` instead of `flex-box`, it won't be very nice eventually when you have more stuff added or re-arrange later on would be the nightmare.

Comment: In 2023, this is the CORRECT/BEST answer, plus it works with parents with undefined height, which is a HUGE plus.